# WSO2 Please check password policy at DC for user

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

we trying to add new user to AD as secondary store  in WSO2 but we got this problem

[image]

we tried to get more details from log file but we found the following :

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-01-04 23:25:19,052] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager} -  value after escaping special characters in user02 : user02 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-01-04 23:25:19,062] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for user with SearchFilter: (&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=user02)) in SearchBase:  
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-01-04 23:25:19,065] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Name in space for user02 is CN=user02,CN=Users,DC=DEVDC,DC=sure,DC=com,DC=sa 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-01-04 23:25:19,072] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching for role: rolhejazi 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-01-04 23:25:19,072] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Using search filter: (&(objectcategory=group)(cn=rolhejazi)) 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-01-04 23:25:19,077] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Searching in CN=Users,DC=devdc,DC=sure,DC=com,DC=sa 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-01-04 23:25:19,080] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Is role: rolhejazi exist: true 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-01-04 23:25:19,082] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager} -  Modifying role: CN=rolhejazi with type: 1 user: CN=user02,CN=Users,DC=DEVDC,DC=sure,DC=com,DC=sa in search base: CN=Users,DC=devdc,DC=sure,DC=com,DC=sa 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-01-04 23:25:19,400] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager} -  User: CN=user02,CN=Users,DC=DEVDC,DC=sure,DC=com,DC=sa was successfully modified in LDAP group: CN=rolhejazi 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-01-04 23:25:19,402]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager} -  Unsecured connection is being used. Enabling user account operation will fail 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-01-04 23:25:19,411] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.UserRealmProxy} -  Error while enabling the user account. Please check password policy at DC for user : user02 
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error while enabling the user account. Please check password policy at DC for user : user02
```

Comment: As a suggestion, could u add the same user with the same password directly to the AD itself, to see whether it is failing as well?

Comment: i tried add the same user with the same password directly to the AD  and user created successfully

Comment: What are values you have configured for PasswordJavaRegEx and PasswordJavaScriptRegEx in the userstore manager? and add a sample password you have tried.

Comment: <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>                                                                       

 <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>

password sample P@s$word@123